# What can be inferred about the eigenvalues given this phase portrait?

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

It looks like a spiral and at the same time, looks like a normal node? How do I differentiate?

Comment: It approaches zero.

Comment: Eigenvalue is negative

Answer (score 2):

This is definitely a node and the solution curves swirl toward the origin, hence the node is stable.

Stable nodes have negative eigenvalues and degenerate nodes have repeated eigenvalues, in both cases the eigenvalues are real.

Futher inspection infers that all solutions seem to approach the origin along a single eigenvector, meaning this is a *stable degenerate node*.

$ $(Note that degenerate nodes can also generate more than one eigenvector but it is clear in this case all solutions near the origin are tangential to one single eigenvector)

Thus, this phase portrait implies negative repeated real eigenvalues from which only one single linearly independent eigenvector can be determined.

Comment: but there is a possibility for this phase portrait to be spiral sink?

Comment: It's just different conventions. When the eigenvalues are complex, it's a spiral. But some use the word "spiral" in both scenarios with complex or real eigenvalues. In case of complex eigenvalues, you have stable and unstable spirals and they look more circular than spiral nodes. The word "spiral sink" implies a stable node and "spiral source" means unstable node. Nodes after all look kind of like spirals, especially the degenerate ones, but they only spiral near the origin, the farther away from the origin the less they behave like spirals

Comment: ...unlike the spirals generated by complex eigenvalues, which always spiral

Comment: Your explaination helps in clarifying my doubts. tk u.